# getting empty field after state update

Tags: reactjs

i have two methods to load different things, but they work with the same state.
After success of the first one i call the second one but somehow the field initialized by the first method gets empty.
here is my state :

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    name: "",
    photo: "",
    description: "",
    categories: [],
    price: "",
    category: "",
    loading: false,
    errorMsg: "",
    stock: "",
    createdProduct: "",
    getRedirect: "",
    formData: "",
  });
```

here are my two methods :

```
  const preloadCategory = () => {
    getAllCategory().then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        setInputs({ ...inputs, error: data.error });
      } else {
        setInputs({
          ...inputs,
          error: "",
          categories: data,
          formData: new FormData(),
        });
        preload(match.params.productId);
      }
    });
  };
  const preload = (productId) => {
    getProduct(productId).then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        setInputs({ ...inputs, error: data.error });
      } else {
        setInputs({
          ...inputs,
          name: data.name,
          description: data.description,
          price: data.price,
          stock: data.stock,
          category: data.category,
          formData: new FormData(),
        });
      }
    });
  };
```

When second method called , categories are empty

Comment: `setState` updates state asynchronously, so iterative calls can't presume previous calls have already taken effect. See https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html for ways to handle this.

Comment: in console.log() i can see the change ...or when i do {JSON.stringify(inputs)} on the page ... so categories are being updated

Comment: But not before `preload` is called. The solution is to have a `useEffect` which listens for changes to the state object (i.e. when `inputs.categories` has a length) and then calls `preload`.

Comment: i do   useEffect(() => {
    preloadCategory();
  }, []);    categories are being fulfilled before preload(...) @lawrence-witt

Comment: does the state gets empty before we update it ??

Comment: `preload` is executing before `setInputs` is able to update the state.

Comment: ok but the question is why categories go empty ? after the arrays is filled @Adnomination how can i update state and dont lose previous values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at this some more I see the main issue isn't actually the asynchronous nature of the setter function. Although that's definitely still worth considering because you are taking it on faith that your `preload` API call completes after it has finished, which is not guaranteed.

The main problem is that you are passing stale values to `preload`. When you set up this effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    preloadCategory();
}, [])
```

You are working with a snapshot of the state object as it exists when the component is first mounted. Since `preload` is called from within `preloadCategory`, any use of the spread `...inputs` refers to this snapshot and not the state object as it may now exist. That's why `preload` will always use the old values, regardless of whether the setter function above it has completed.

A simple solution is to use the setter function callback syntax, which will ensure you are using up to date values:

```
setInputs(i => ({
  ...i,
  name: data.name,
  description: data.description,
  price: data.price,
  stock: data.stock,
  category: data.category,
  formData: new FormData(),
}));
```

However, as mentioned in the comments, what you really ought to be doing is separating the logic into separate `useEffects` so that `preload` is only called once the correct data is in state.

Comment: This should answer all your questions. Thanks for describing it so well.

Comment: solved with making new state for categories... but thanks for this info , didin't know it